# Notedpad ++ replace string with a random number

Tags: notepad++

Does anyone know a plugin or method to replace a string
that repeat itself on every line with a random number between
1,0000-100,000 ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can do this with Notepad++ alone but you could try the [python script plugin](https://github.com/bruderstein/PythonScript) for notepad++.